# comparing two unequal data frames and replacing string from one of the data frame based on the second data frame

Tags: r, machine-learning, rstudio

I want to write a function in R, which can compare two unequal data frames and modify the contents of the first data frame based on the result of comparison

```
static_graph_DF = data.frame(node= #10000 nodes#, label = rep("suceptible",10000))
infecteNodes_DF = data.frame(node=#random 1000 nodes from the above mentioned nodes #, label = rep("infected",1000))
```

What I want to do is, find the nodes in static_graph_DF that are infected(i.e. by checking whether infecteNodes_DF is in static_graph_DF ) and replace the label of static_graph_DF from "susceptible" to "infected" .

I know that using **merge()**, **%in%**, **match()** functions, I can write the function, but still I am stuck with this function and not able to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a numeric type of `node`, no function is necessary.

```
levels(static_graph_DF$label) <- c("suceptible","infected")
static_graph_DF$label[infecteNodes_DF$node] <- "infected"
```

Comment: I am getting the following error message while doing so "Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, infected$infected_nodes, value = c(NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated"

Comment: I tried your solution for smaller dataset, long<-data.frame(UniqID=sample(letters[1:20],20),label=rep("sus",20))
short<-data.frame(UniqID=sample(letters[1:20],10),label=rep("inf",10))     long$label[short$UniqID] = "inf"  BUT still it doesnt work, gives the same above error. You can use this dataset to check your solution

Comment: Modify the first statement to use your level names. Check `help(levels) ` for more details why